# Gatling 2: concurrent request handling

Tags: asynchronous, concurrency, resources, exec, gatling

I have a question regarding the behavior of Gatling when using `.exec` in combination with `.resources`. 
The [documentation](http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.4/cheat-sheet.html) describes the behavior very briefly:

> Allows to fetch resources in parallel in order to emulate the
>   behaviour of a real web browser

Let's consider the following, simple scenario:

```
  val scn = scenario("Test Scenario")
    .exec(
      http("Base Page").get("/")
        .resources(
          http("Resource A").get(host + "/resource_a.js"),
          http("Resource B").get(host + "/resource_b.js")
        )
    )

    .exec(
      http("Resource X").get(host + "/resource_x.js")
    )
```

My question is: When is the second `.exec` block for *Resource X* being executed?

a) As soon as the "main request" of the first `.exec` block returns (i.e. when the *Base Page* request returns)

b) When all requests of the first `.exec` block returned (i.e. when the *Base Page* as well as *Resource A* and *Resource B* have been fetched)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer is: b, when all resources have been fetched.